# Wordpress memory error issue

Tags: database, wordpress, memory

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3559
```

Has anybody any idea what this could be and why it appears when I hit the **login button** on the Wordpress admin panel? Also the website doesn't behave like before, it seams like the database is corrupted or something is terribly broken. It shows only the front page correct moste other pages are broken?

I found some more error's no idea what the error is about?

WordPress database error: [Out of resources when opening file '/tmp/#sql_319c_0.MYD' (Errcode: 24)]

Comment: this is mostly due to low server hardware resourse

Comment: Have you also been making changes to the code? Ocassionally, I make a wrong edit causing the entire layout/display of the pages to change.

Comment: No this happened during the weekend, but we didn't change anything this weekend. The client try to add some new things in wordpress. Maybe a database update or insert went wrong and made the database corrupt. It's dedicated server so hardware is not the problem, more then enough resources on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');` in `wp-config.php` file or add `ob_start();` at the beginning of your theme 'function.php' file.

Comment: The above methods do not work for me. Could it be a broken plug-in or something that leaks memory? Also the pages don't work properly. In some cases a fancybox neads to appear with a wordpress page loaded inside. Now it doesn't load a fancybox at all or it does load a fancybox but with the frontpage loaded inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what the problem was but it seams to be a server issue. Sever wasn't responding as it should respond. We placed a copy back on the server that didn't help. We reseted the server and now everything is working just fine again. They where thinking maybe somebody was trying to hack the server!

Comment: Ok the problem apperently the problem is still not solved by just rebooting the server. After one week the problem shows itself again.
Almost identical to the last time. I think it is a caching issue, but don't know exactly witch part of the caching is creating the problem. If it is the plug-in or a server settings ... no clew until now.